# Handle events from multiple mouses on the same PC on Win7 or newer

Tags: c#, events, windows-7, mouse, multipoint

So far, the best language that I have known for this case is C# but I'd love to know if other languages can do it. I need to plug multiple mouses to the computer and handle their events separately.

for **example**: 
    Mouse1.MouseDragged() will move the cursor. 
    Mouse2.MouseDragged() will make a sound or print something and NOT do what Mouse1.MouseDragged() does.

I know there is a Microsoft Multipoint SDK but I cannot seem to make it work.
The rest of the applications out there for Multiple Mouses are for WinXP so I cant make them work.

Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: You only have one mouse pointer on the screen.  Mouse input is merged before it is injected into the input event queue.  Recognizing input from multiple mice requires detecting them before merging occurs, like you can do with raw input (look up GetRawInputData).  The multipoint sdk is very different, it creates multiple pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a very long research i found my solution thanks to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) comment.

What i did was creating a small Win32 App in Visual Studio to catch raw input from Mouse and Keyboard using Windows.h and i simply make it send keystrokes whenever i drag a specific mouse.
i still need to solve many problems, but so far it works.

Thanks a lot